# How to setup testopia 2.5 on already installed bugzilla 4.2

Tags: testing

We are using bugzilla 4.2 in our organization.
I want setup testopia 2.5 on this.
We have done some customization on bugzilla while setting up.
I want to retain them but as well as want to configure testopia on it.
Can anybody explain how to setup testopia on linux when bugzilla already installed with customization?

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade to Bugzilla > 4.2.1. and then you can install Testopia 2.5 without any patching.
Installation of Testopia is straightforward.

More 
details : https://web.archive.org/web/20140326234952/http://lpsolit.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/testopia-2-5-released-works-with-bugzilla-4-2-1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Testopia from mozilla:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Bugzilla/Testopia
2. Move this file to your Bugzilla folder and extract it there.
3. Go to terminal and navigate to your Bugzilla folder
4. Run ./checksetup.pl from terminal to complete Testopia installation.